# Custom output cache provider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, utc, outputcache

I'm creating a custom output cache provider by implementing the `OutputCacheProvider` class in an ASP.NET MVC application.

In the below methods,

```
public override object Add(string key, object entry, DateTime expiryDate)
{
   // 
}

public override void Set(string key, object entry, DateTime expiryDate)
{
  //
}
```

The `expiryDate` is in UTC or server time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a **utcExpiry** [as per msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.outputcacheprovider.add.aspx)

(OutputCacheProvider.Add Method)

```
public abstract Object Add(
    string key,
    Object entry,
    DateTime utcExpiry
)
```